# Computer can't resolve other computer names

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dhcp

I have a network with DHCP/DNS/AD setup with Windows 2012 server. Users cannot resolve computer names on the network without entering their FQDN, i.e. "server", but "server.domain.com" does.

The only way for me to make this work is to specify a DNS domain in the DHCP scope options, but that breaks some linux servers which are on another domain.

Is there a way for computers to resolve computer names without adding DNS domain in DHCP? From what I understand WINS is a dead technology so shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows domain member computers will, by default, automatically add the domain's name as a DNS search suffix. For non-domain member machines (or non-Windows machines), though, providing the domain name via DHCP or specifying it in a configuration file are typically the only means used to configure a DNS suffix.

If I were in your position I'd figure out what "breaks" on "some linux servers" (sic) and resolve that problem, as opposed to trying to cook up some non-standard way to provide the domain name to client machines.

Comment: Thanks, that's the conclusion that I came to. I'm trying to figure out a work around for the linux servers now, rather than messing with the rest of the network.